# moving files from multiple locations to a single location using Python

Tags: python

I have a long list of files from multiple folders and I would like to have them all in a single location so far I have:

```
import os
import shutil

dest_folder = 'C:\\dest_folder'
files = [
    'file1.csv', 'file2.csv',
    'file3.csv',
    ]
 for f in files:
    shutil.copy(f, 'dest_folder')
```

This is not working for me and I cant seem to figure out why, any help would be great, thanks

Comment: Likely you’ll need to provide the *explicit* path to the files.  How else is the program to know where the files are located; unless the script is in the same directory.

Comment: just add your script into the folder which you have the files.(file1.csv file2.csv)

Comment: @cesebe27 - Preferably not, as this isn’t maintainable.  OP should give the explicit paths to the files.

Comment: it's arguable I think, explicit paths can also change, so is that look maintainable?

Comment: Need to provide absolute path of all source files

Comment: In future, please specify *how* it's not working, including the full error message and stack trace if there is one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with this kind of stuff, but I'm not sure if you meant to have 'dest_folder' in quotes at the end.

Comment: That was exactly the issue, and now I feel really silly for asking. Thank you though!